# Resizing SVG on Angular

Tags: angular, svg, resize

I am working with Angular (not AngularJS) and I am trying to insert a circle graph on my project.

HTML code is:

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">
  <path class="circle"
    stroke-dasharray="60, 100"
    d="M18 2.0845
      a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
      a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
  />
  </svg>
```

CSS code is:

```
.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.circle {
  stroke: #4CC790;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.8pt;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0, 100;
  }
}
```

If you try to see this graph in a HTML page you don't have any problems. You can resize as you want. But if you try to insert this code in your Angular project graph show very small and I can't resize it!

I've tried everything! I have made all kind of changes on CSS and nothing. I don't know how resize it... :(

Comment: how do you resize?

Comment: If I write this code in a html and css file, only I change "max-height" of "circular-chart" class and I resize it. But if I change this properties in my Angular project nothing happend...

Comment: Please find a way to include a [mcve] in your question.  As you have admitted, what you have posted here works. So it doesn't help solve your problem. So it must be somthing else related to the way you are using it in Angular.  We need to see the issue in action ino order to help you.

Comment: You only need create an Angular project (not AngularJS project) and insert this code into an Angular component to see that you can't resize the graph.

Comment: See i tried your code here and it works..please make any changes here to show us the problem. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbf4in

Comment: Yes, in the index.html it works perfectly, but if you try to run it in ANGULAR COMPONENT you can't resize it and it sees very small.

Answer (score 0):

Just transform your class
for example:
CSS

```css
.circular-chart {
  display: block;
 -webkit-transform: scale(3);
  transform: scale(3);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question and add a bit more explanation of the solution, also relate it more to the question. For more guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer